# Ambiguous column name with join query in Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Table setup:

I got ambiguous column name ?... In my first table, the column that the sqlalchemy is joining on, does not exist.

However, in the sqlite browser, the relationship has been made.

```
class Parent:
    childs = db.relationship('Child',
                                   backref=db.backref('parent', lazy='joined'),
                                   lazy='select',
                                   )
class Child:
     parents = db.column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey='parents.id')
     siblings = db.relationship('Sibling', backref=db.backref'child', lazy='select')

class Sibling:
     childs = db.column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey='child.id')
```

The query:

```
def json_join():
   data = db.session.query(Parent, Child, Sibling)\
    .join(Parent)\
    .join(Child)\
    .join(Sibling)\
    .filter(Parent.id == Child.id == Sibling.id)\
    .all()
   return data
```

error:
ambiguous column name child.id

I think:
The relationship in the Parent column does not create the column for the Child-relation? So no join...

Answer (score -1):

See the docs for one to many relationships for Parent to Children:
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-one

```py
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'))
    child = relationship("Child", back_populates="parents")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship("Parent", back_populates="child")
```

Also see the docs for many to many relationships for Children and Siblings (given as parents and children): https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many

```py
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', Integer, ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', Integer, ForeignKey('right.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship(
        "Child",
        secondary=association_table,
        back_populates="parents")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parents = relationship(
        "Parent",
        secondary=association_table,
        back_populates="children")
```

Comment: Thank you, I did read this. But is there then a difference in the syntax flask-SQLAlchemy and SQLAlchemy?